# How to write path for image in same folder as CSS file?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a background image to a div. The image is in the same folder as my CSS file. I am certain the path is right because it was working earlier and I copied the path directly from my computer.

Why does the path `CSS\presentation.jpg` not work? What am I missing?

Thank you!

[image: My file hierarchy]

```css
.second-container {
    position:relative;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
    background-color: #edffea;
    background-image: url("CSS\presentation.jpg");
}
```

Comment: If it's in the same folder you should write the file name directly `url("presentation.jpg")`.
Also, your slash has the wrong direction: you have `CSS\presentation.jpg` and should be `CSS/presentation.jpg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In css file we use relative paths, so correct style will be

```
.second-container{
         position:relative;
         text-align: center;
         padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
         background-color: #edffea;
         background-image: url("presentation.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question @AidOnline01!  That was THE solution.